# Which tool can be used to generate a diagram of functions executed annotated with execution times?

Tags: drupal

I'm using Drupal and would like to get a graph of functions called annotated with the times the functions took to execute. I found this image which demonstrates what I'm looking for:

[image: http://drupal.org/files/purge.png]

However, I can't find a tool that can produce a similar image. What kind of tool am I looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

Comment: I'm using zend debugger in Win OS. XDebug can not work with php5.2.

Comment: Likely because PHP 5.2 is not supported anymore. PHP 5.3 was released in 2009-06-30, nearly 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

[XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof) can generate call graph images similar to this, but not exactly the same. I believe Google searching using keywords **PHP call graph** or **drupal call graph** will provide you more information.